# Datagridview won't change cell color

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have tried everything to make this change colors it seems. I have read through a lot of stackoverflow posts and have not found my answer. The colors changed before I made the datatable populate data from the database. After that they quit changing colors. Here is my code that is firing on CellFormatting event.

```
        public ScheduleUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView.CellClick += (s, e) => OnCellClick(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
        dataGridView.CellFormatting += (s, e) => CellFormating(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
        btnAll.Click += (s, e) => Filter(Filters.All);
        btnHourly.Click += (s, e) => Filter(Filters.Hourly);
        btnSalary.Click += (s, e) => Filter(Filters.Salary);
    }

private void CellFormating(int c, int r)
    {
        var cell = dataGridView[c, r];
        var tagObject = cell.Tag;
        if (tagObject == null)
        {
            cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            var tagType = tagObject.GetType();
            if (tagType == typeof(DayOff))
            {
                var avail = (DayOff)tagObject;
                if (avail != null)
                {
                    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Firebrick;
                }
            }
            else
            if (tagType == typeof(DayOffRequest))
            {
                var request = (DayOffRequest)tagObject;
                if (request.Status == DayOffRequest.RequestStatus.Approved)
                {
                    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
                }
                else
                if (request.Status == DayOffRequest.RequestStatus.Pending)
                {
                    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
                }
            }
            else
            if (tagType == typeof(Shift))
            {
                cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated it. Debugging and stepping through it says it executes the cell.style changes but the datagridview just doesn't show those changes.

Comment: I think, it because your if conditions not working as expected. What is your `cell.Tag` value? It's either `null`, or non of that types in `if` conditions.

Comment: A databound grid behaves differently, and you may need to do a `dataGridView.Refresh()` after setting the new colours.

Comment: @SeM-ՍեՄ the code in the if conditions get executed(cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White; cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Firebrick;) for instance but color isn't updated in the grid Peter Abolins I call both refresh and update but colors still do not change.

Comment: is `CellFormating` method only point, where you changing the cell styles? Cause I've created the small example and it works fine.

Comment: Also if you change the cell style in cell formatting  event it will run endlessly.

Comment: @SeM-ՍեՄ yes that is the only event I am using to set my colors. Like I said it worked fine until I populated my gridview with data from my database. Once I did that colors quit working all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating recursion by changing cell style in `CellFormating()` method and it can cause unexpected results. So try to set your cell styles in different event, for example in `DataBindingComplete`.

Comment: Thanks just everywhere I looked at before said it had to be in the CellFormating event. So that is where I put it and it was working until I did the database change. Weird. But thanks again!